# jquery click "this"

Tags: jquery, html

If  do  this

```
$this.find('div').click(customFunc); // inside customFunc , $(this) is a div
```

If  do  this

```
$this.find('div').keypress(
    function(e) {  
       customFunc();
    }
 );   // inside customFunc , $(this) is a window
```

I want when keypress is called, inside `customFuc()`,  `$(this)` is `div`.

How to do that and maintain using `function(e)` for keypress?

Comment: `$this` and `$(this)` can be two different things.

Comment: Please have a look at these resources to learn how `this` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use customFunc directly.

```
$this.find('div').keypress(customFunc);
```

Otherwise, you can apply a context to it with .call or .apply

```
$this.find('div').keypress(function(e){
    customFunc.call(this);
});
```

Comment: =) i want to maintain using function(e){} for keypress

Comment: So add another `keypress` event handler.

Comment: `$this.find('div').keypress(...).keypress(...)`